# Filtering data while joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, where-clause

I have 2 tables, I want to filter the data from both the tables before the 2 tables are joined together.

Customer Table:

```
   ╔══════════╦═══════╗
   ║ Customer ║ Year  ║
   ╠══════════╬═══════╣
   ║ A        ║ 2018  ║
   ║ B        ║ 2019  ║
   ║ C        ║ 2020  ║
   ╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

Entry Table:

```
   ╔══════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
   ║ Customer ║ Entry ║ Category ║
   ╠══════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
   ║ A        ║  5575 ║ D        ║
   ║ A        ║  6532 ║ C        ║
   ║ A        ║  3215 ║ D        ║
   ║ A        ║  5645 ║ M        ║
   ║ B        ║  3331 ║ A        ║
   ║ B        ║  4445 ║ D        ║
   ╚══════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

I want to Left Join so I get all records from the Customer table with year 2019 and 2020..Also,i want to filter on category D in the entry table before the join.

Desired Results:

```
   ╔══════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
   ║ Customer ║ Year  ║ Entry ║
   ╠══════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
   ║          ║       ║       ║
   ║          ║       ║       ║
   ║ B        ║ 2019  ║  4445 ║
   ║ C        ║ 2020  ║  NULL ║
   ╚══════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

If I was to do the following query:

`SELECT Customer.Customer, Customer.Year, Entry.Entry
   FROM Customer
   LEFT JOIN Entry
   ON Customer.Customer=Entry.Customer
   WHERE customer.year in ('2019','2020') and Entry.Category='D'`

Also, it can be done with below query also

`SELECT Customer.Customer, Customer.Year, Entry.Entry
   FROM (select * from Customer where year in ('2019','2020')) Customer
   LEFT JOIN (select * from Entry where Category='D') Entry
   ON Customer.Customer=Entry.Customer`

Which query would be more optimised and faster?

Thanks to any help in advance!!

Comment: For questions like these, it’s best to check the query execution plan for both queries and compare them. For SQL Server, you can use the option to [Include Actual Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) in Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want filtering both in the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c.Year, e.Entry
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN
     Entry e
     ON c.Customer = e.Customer AND e.Category = 'D'
WHERE c.year in ('2019', '2020');
```

Note that if `year` is a number, then drop the single quotes in the `IN` values.

As a general rules, filters on the *first* table in a `LEFT JOIN` go in the `WHERE` clause.  Filters on subsequent tables go on the `ON` clause.